# Text Slide Jumping Fade In and Out

Tags: jquery, html, css

My current problem is when i try making a slide with text using jquery when one text fades out the other fades in but there is a gap right before fadeIn I am trying to make it smooth so it looks normal.

Code: [JSFIDDLE][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/zsvL3Lsf/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the two lines of code run at almost the same time. Try this code, where you can also put a delay in the complete function if you need it.

```
$('#_wel').delay(2000).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    $('#_one').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: If i wanted to do the fadeout and fadein for three h1 tags how would i do it so it loops like #_one #_two #_three all different text fade in and out like the code above

Comment: you mean something like that?   `$('#_wel').delay(2000).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    $('#_one').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        $('#_two').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            $('#_three').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
`

Comment: then how would i loop it would i use fadeloop?

Comment: I changed your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/alcoolis/j8o7e7ta/3/) to initialise your #_wel div and loop the #_one, #_two, and #_three divs as well